# Cannot deploy Razor Pages website

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I built a simple Razor Pages website in order to show some views on a couple of database tables.

In the `index.cshtml.cs` I just have:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        return RedirectToPage("./Registrations/Index");
    }
}
```

In the `Registrations/index.cshtml.cs` I have:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    int pageSize = 30;

    private readonly RegistrationAdmin.PostgresDbContext _context;

    public IndexModel(RegistrationAdmin.PostgresDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public PaginatedList<Registration> Registration { get; set; }

    public async Task OnGetAsync(int pageIndex = 1)
    {
        IQueryable<Registration> registrations = _context.Registrations
            .Include(r => r.ContactPerson)
            .Include(r => r.Badge)
            .OrderByDescending(r => r.RegistrationId);

        this.Registration = await PaginatedList<Registration>.
                            CreateAsync(registrations.AsNoTracking(), pageIndex, pageSize);
    }
}
```

Testing the website from Visual Studio is fine, and running from the project directory with `dotnet run` is also fine.

So I deployed the website with:

`dotnet publish -o ../Published/ -c release`

then run it with `dotnet MyWebsite.dll` from the publish directory.

When I connect to http://localhost:5000, I get a general error.

Looking at the console this is the exception thrown:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
  An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.InvalidOperationException: No page named './Registrations/Index' matches the supplied values.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.RedirectToPageResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, RedirectToPageResult result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RedirectToPageResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultAsync(IActionResult result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResultFilterAsync[TFilter,TFilterAsync]()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

I can't understand what's wrong with deployed version.

Comment: why don't you give ref of action, something like this `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Registrations");`

Comment: and make sure you create that action, in registrations controller

Comment: Ok, I'll try. But I can't understand why it works before deploy and it doesn't work after.

Comment: Are you deploying your views along with the compiled source code?

Comment: Mmmh, i don't know... I just run the `publish` command, then `cd` to directory, and run `dotnet MyWebsite.dll`. Do I have to manually copy some files from project directory to publish one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the error message, some how the app is not seeing the referenced views.

By default when published the project precompiles the pages.

Reference [Publishing and deploying a Razor Pages application to IIS on Windows](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/publishing/publish-to-iis)

though you have indicated that you are on mac

> It is possible to skip this step and to publish the raw *.cshtml*
>   files, resulting in pages that are updateable in a similar way to PHP,
>   classic ASP or the ASP.NET Web Pages frameworks. In other words, you
>   can make changes to the .cshtml files and then copy them to the web
>   server while the application is running, **and the new content will take
>   effect immediately.**
>
> If you would like to adopt this approach, add an `MvcCompileOnPublish`
>   node to your *.csproj* file, with the value set to `false`:
>
> ```
> <PropertyGroup>
>     <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
>     <MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>false</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
> </PropertyGroup>
> ```
>
> This will result in a Pages folder containing the content pages and a
>   refs folder containing the libraries required for the application

Using the above approach, while more of a work around would allow you to copy the missing views over to the published app and make them available for use when publishing.

**Edit**:

So in the end it looks like there was an issue with the *csproj* file that was excluding the pages when published.

We were able to confirm that by disabling pages pre-compilation and see the problem pages were not being copied (considered), when published.

Cleaning the *csproj* file and recompiling solved the issue for both pre compiled and non compiled copied pages.

It worked originally in the project directly because all the necessary files were present when the project was run.